# jQuery quiz with differential questions

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I've got a quiz to set up with 10 questions, with each one of the questions having 4 answers out of which one is correct. Okay, these questions are structured in the following way:

- 3 easy ones
- one differential question with two answers (basically the next step depends on this one. If the user picks one of the answers goes to a path and, obviously, if it picks the other one they take the other path
- 5 more questions which are being defined by the previous question
- one extra question.

Now, the ***3 easy ones*** will be more than 3, but only 3 will be picked randomly from an array. ***The differential*** one is only one and will always stay the same. The ***5 more questions*** are being split into two different arrays (there are more than 5 in each of that specific array, the questions being chosen randomly yet again). And once the user has answered the 5 questions it will receive ***one more question*** picked randomly from two different arrays, based on the differential question he or she picked.

This is supposed to be the logic behind the script. Now, my problem is that I'm not really efficient in these arrays or jSON for that matter and I haven't got a slightest clue on how exactly should the **if**'s look like.

It would be highly appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: You should post some code and your json and your tries,

Answer (score 0):

Being "not really efficient in these arrays or JSON" means you are far away from building "quiz engine" by yourself. Try to make smaller steps and learn little more about javascript first.

You can parse json files and get them as javascript array with (note calling function **onQuestionsLoaded**)

```
$.getJSON('https://domain.com/file.json', function(data) {         
   onQuestionsLoaded(data);
});
```

For your purpose I would build quizz structure in json format like this (note **"assume"**)

```
[
   {
      "question": "How are you?",
      "order": 1,
      "answers": [
         {
            "option": "a",
            "answer": "Not very well."
         }, {
            "option": "b",
            "answer": "I am pretty fine, thank you."
         }
      ]
   }, {
      "question": "How can I help you then?",
      "order": 2,
      "assume": {"order": 1, "answer": "a"},
      "answers": [
         { .. }
      ]
   }, {
      "question": "Nice to hear that!",
      "order": 2,
      "assume": {"order": 1, "answer": "b"},
      "answers": [
         { .. }
      ]
   }
]
```

while in javascript you can use something like

```
var questions = []; //will hold all questions
var answers = []; //will hold answers given by the user, so we can show questions based on previous answers

function onQuestionsLoaded(data){ //called after json is loaded and parsed
   prepareQuestions(data); //here we prepare array of questions so we can read questions by their order
   showQuestion(1); //showing first question
}

function prepareQuestions(data){
   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
      if(questions.hasOwnProperty(i))
         questions[data[i].order].push(data[i]);
}

function showQuestion(order){
   var nextQuestion = getNextQuestion(order);
   if(nextQuestion != null){
      $('#currentQuestion').html(nextQuestion.question);
      //and more to show particular question
   }
}

function getNextQuestion(order){
   if(!questions.hasOwnProperty(order)){
      alert('Question with order ['+ order +'] does not exist.');
      return null;
   } else {
      if(questions[order].length > 1){ //if question by given order has more variants
         return pickVariant(order);
      } else return questions[order][0]; //getting a first question in given order
   }   
}

function pickVariant(order){
   for(var i = 0; i < questions[order].length; i++)
      if(questions.hasOwnProperty(i)){
         var question = questions[order][i];
         if(answers[question.assume.order] == question.assume.answer) //desired "if" for checking if the some of previous question was answered by assumed answer
            return question;
      }

   return null; //for case that none of questions belongs to given answer
}

function answerQuestion(order, option){ //you call this when user selects the answer, where the argument "option" is "b" for "I am pretty fine, thank you"
   answers[order] = option; //remember the answer, so we get 1 = b, 2 = a, 3 = d .. and so on
   showQuestion(order + 1); //showing the next question
}
```

I haven't tested anything of this. It's meant to be just the way, you still need to learn a little about arrays and JSONs elsewhere.

Comment: Can you please share some working demo? This will be helpful.